# Google App Marketplace listing - can't find my app

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have successfully published our app on Google App Marketplace and it can be found when navigating from Google Mail interface, but when I search the Google Marketplace 
https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?query=upsafe
 for our app  I don't find anything

Has anyone else come across such issue?

Many thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

That's because that is the old Marketplace. New applications are listed only in the new Marketplace, the one you can access from the Admin Console.

There I was able to find your application easily.

If you need to have a URL redirecting to your app, in the new Marketplace, search for you app and then click on it. You will see the "Install app" button and at the right you will see a button to share it. 
Click on it and you can share it with Google+ and with Gmail or Get the Link.

Another way to get the URL is in the Chrome dashboard. There click on edit of your application and at the bottom there is a button that says "Preview Changes", click it and it will take you to the same link.

I hope this helps.